# define flag variable in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new in Django and I am trying to search for something in a template if I find it a want to print something, if not I want to print something else.
sth like this:

```
{% for art in artifacts %}
{% if art.product_component == 'A' %}
<p> something.</p>
{{ found = True }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if not found  %}
<p>NA</p>
{% endif %}
```

I know this is not the right way to do it, but this is just to understand the idea.

how can i do it?

Comment: i think the simple way is define `found` in views context. or write custom filter.

Comment: You can't create new variables and assign values to variables in Django templates (except using `{% with ... as .. %}` which is a one-time assignment and won't help you here). You can with jinja2 templating language btw. So you really need to either define your own template tag to assign a value to a variable or the easiest, figure out in the view whether `found` is true of false and pass it into the rendering context.

Comment: can you please explain it more?
I think understand the concept but I have no idea how to do it :(

Answer (score 2):

You can write a templatetag for finding `product_component == 'A'` is exist or not.

**your_app_dir/templatetags/product_tag.py**

```
from django import template
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.assignment_tag()
def check_product_component_status(artifacts):
    value =  [art for art in artifacts if art.product_component == 'A']
    if value:
        return True
    return False
```

template:

```
{% for art in artifacts %}
    {% if art.product_component == 'A' %}
        <p> something.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% load product_tag %}
{% check_product_component_status artifacts as status %}
{% if not status %}
    <p> something.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: when i tried this i got this error: TemplateSyntaxError: 'WSRR_Tag' is not a registered tag library.

Comment: Could you please share your tempate and template tag code? Where you placed templatetags folder. It must be inside any of the installed apps. What is your templatetag module name? you must load your module name in template just like {% load WSRR_Tag %}, here I assue your module name is WSRR_Tag.